# Java set values after if else loop in one line

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

How do I achieve setting the value inside if else in one line?

```
String amount = myJSON.optString("cValue")
double cValue = (amount != null && !amount.isEmpty()) ? Double.parseDouble(amount) : 0;
if (cValue > 0) {
    mySavings.setCouponValue(cValue);
} else {
    mySavings.setCouponValue(0.0);
}
```

Comment: try the ternary operator again. which you have used.

Comment: You already have the logic in your code `<condition> ? <if true> : <if false>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply do :

```
mySavings.setCouponValue((cValue > 0 ? cValue : 0.0));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can code like this:

`mySavings.setCouponValue((cValue > 0 ? cValue : 0.0));`

Further you can use `assert` in your method to avoid if else.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use a ternary operator to set the value, without having to create a temporary variable "cValue", just for comparison

```
String amount = myJSON.optString("cValue")
mySavings.setCouponValue((amount != null && !amount.isEmpty()) ? Double.parseDouble(amount) : 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative if you're using Java 8 or above, you can do like this :

```
mySavings.setCouponValue(Optional.ofNullable(amount).map(cValue -> !cValue.isEmpty() ?  Double.parseDouble(cValue):0).orElse(0.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness

```
mySavings.setCouponValue(Math.max(0.0, cValue));
```

Useful if you were really committed to writing terrifying "one liners". In this case by avoiding introducing the `cValue` variable.